# AWS Java SDK error: request signature 'not match signature provided' Check your key, etc. But credentials are correct

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, credentials, signing

**UPDATE**: This was my stupid copy/paste error with keys.  Some other interesting aspects to this which i will try to explain shortly...

**ORIGINAL QUESTION FOLLOWS:**

I was trying to write a Spark program that writes JSON to S3 and ran into this error:
**Request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.**

So I decided to try to get things working the simplest possible way, with the AWS Java SDK, and the sample program described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html)

With my credentials correctly provided in ~/.aws/credentials the sample
code referenced above worked without modification.

I then decided to break things by moving ~/.aws/credentials aside and rerunning, and of course it errored out. Then I tried fixing by explicitly providing the credentials. You can see the full code
of the slightly modified sample program in the section 'FULL MODIFIED PROGRAM'.

But the essence of what I tried is given immediately below. Note that I am supplying the credentials
via

```
.withCredentials(provider)
```

on the s3Client builder.  I also tried running with the line below both commented out and enabled:

```
//.withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
```

.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String bucketName = "cbedford-sqlshackdemocli-test-only";
        String stringObjKeyName = "durango.saturday1";
        String fileObjKeyName = "clean.money.txt";
        String fileName = "/tmp/x";

        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        // Solution is update the Signer Version.
        clientConfiguration.setSignerOverride("S3SignerType");


        AWSCredentialsProvider provider = new  AWSCredentialsProvider() {
            @Override
            public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
                return new AWSCredentials () {
                    @Override
                    public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
                        // String below copied form ~/.aws/credentials 
                        // [default]
                        // aws_access_key_id = somethingsomething
                        return "somethingsomething";        
                    }
                    @Override
                    public String getAWSSecretKey() {
                        // String below copied form ~/.aws/credentials 
                        // [default]
                        // aws_secret_access_key = somethingsomethingelse
                        return "somethingsomethingelse";
                    }
                };
            }
            @Override
            public void refresh() {
            }
        };

        try {
            //This code expects that you have AWS credentials set up per:
            // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                    .withCredentials(provider)
                    //.withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
                    .build();
```

No matter what I tried, I failed in all my attempts to supply the same credentials as those in my .aws directory via the inline method. If any one can spot my dumb mistake (I know I must be making one!) I would be extremely grateful.

**FULL MODIFIED PROGRAM**

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class UploadObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String bucketName = "cbedford-sqlshackdemocli-test-only";
        String stringObjKeyName = "durango.saturday1";
        String fileObjKeyName = "clean.money.txt";
        String fileName = "/tmp/x";

        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        // Solution is update the Signer Version.
        clientConfiguration.setSignerOverride("S3SignerType");


        AWSCredentialsProvider provider = new  AWSCredentialsProvider() {
            @Override
            public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
                return new AWSCredentials () {
                    @Override
                    public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
                        return "somethingsomething";        

                    }
                    @Override
                    public String getAWSSecretKey() {
                        return "somethingsomethingelse";        
                    }
                };
            }
            @Override
            public void refresh() {
            }
        };

        try {
            //This code expects that you have AWS credentials set up per:
            // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                    .withCredentials(provider)
                    //.withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
                    .build();

            // Upload a text string as a new object.
            s3Client.putObject(bucketName, stringObjKeyName, "Uploaded String Object");

            // Upload a file as a new object with ContentType and title specified.
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileObjKeyName, new File(fileName));
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentType("plain/text");
            metadata.addUserMetadata("title", "someTitle");
            request.setMetadata(metadata);
            s3Client.putObject(request);
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process
            // it, so it returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can be related to v4 signing where you need to route the request to the specific AWS region where the the bucket lives. recent regions (london, frankfurt, ...) are v4 signature only.

why not add the hadoop-aws jar for the exact hadoop versions you have in your lib dir *and the exact aws JARs it was built with, and try to use the s3a connector, to see if it works or, if it doesn't, what errors are provided. Then look at the troubleshooting_s3a doc on the hadoop docs and see what possible causes are.